# Confirmation email not sending to some of my customer

Tags: magento-1.7

Not sure what was wrong some of my customer are complains that they does not received their order confirmation emails, But when i tried to test it it works fine my side, i have tested with most of gmail hotmail yahoo id. I am suffering a lot by this issue, Can someone suggest me some idea how to overcome this issue to make a fix, thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to send the emails? Are you using a third party extension? We had an issue where AWS was throttling our emails because they were getting queued at once by a cron. Sometimes it would take many hours before all the emails sent out. We also had emails get refused by AWS because of an issue with using send as, although I don't remember the exact issue.

Also you probably have a mail log on your server like /var/log/mail.log. This should give you some answers if sendmail is failing for some reason.

Comment: Hello Thanks : I am not using any third party extension to send the emails.  
Error log :
 `dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<root>, method=PLAIN, rip=111.21.34.4, lip=178.62.100.134, session=<qXZoS+csWADZk1XW>`
There are many error hit in my mail log i have no idea which the exact one , Can i able to overcome this issue by corn-job ?

Comment: Well, your order confirmation emails send out at the time of the order, right? Try to find an order where the email didn't send and see if an error fire at approx. that time. You might be able to turn something up that way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

is it possible, that the mails are catched by a spam filter?

Many E-Mail account providers filter Mails, when the sender host differs from the actual MX-Record registered. This is to prevent anyone from telling, that they are sending an email from your host.

A solution for this could be to ask your hoster which mx record is registered for your Server. It should be the same as the part in the E-Mail address after the @, from which you are sending your E-Mails. (just a far shot)

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, Can you please give me some example how it need to look exactly, I am not bit sure how to ask with my hosting provider .  For example: My hosting , my domain , my email provider all are different team's .